# Laravel Vuejs | Как расположить файлы стилей для правильной работы приложения

Tags: laravel, vue.js, spa

Разрабатываю приложение с использованием бэкенда в качестве **Laravel** и фронтенда в качестве **VueJS**. Приложение **SPA**. Во **Vue** использую **routes**.

Файлы стилей раскидал в папке **sass**
Имеется несколько файлов: **app**, **variables**, **auth**, **profile**.

Имеется одна входна точка **app.vue** в котором расположен следующий код:

```
<template>
    <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

Далее имеются несколько файлов: **Home.vue**, **Auth.vue**, **Profile.vue**.

Они в себе имеют подключение других модулей.
Собственно в каждом из этих файлов я делаю подключение стилей через:

```
<style lang="sass" scoped>
    @import "../../sass/app.sass"
</style>
```

Но у меня возникают проблемы именно с этим.
Каждый этот файл внутри себя использует ещё роуты и поэтому каждый этот импорт бессмысленно добавлять к каждому компоненту, поэтому я внутри него добавляю селектор **::v-deep** для углубления, но даже суть не в этом.

Суть в том, что я не могу правильно раскидать логику.

Во-первых, каждый мой стиль: **auth.sass**, **app.sass** имеет полноценный код

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800&display=swap')

@import "variables"

*
    outline: none
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
    box-sizing: border-box

a
    color: inherit
    text-decoration: none

    &:hover, &:active, &:focus
        text-decoration: none
        color: inherit

ul, li, ol
    list-style-type: none

body
    font-family: $font-family-default
    background-color: $body-bg
```

Так вот, данный код при импорте ну никак не работает даже на родительский компонент, проблема заключается в селекторах, каждому html элементу задаётся **data-v-782dcf84** , соответственно в стилях соответственно **body[data-v-782dcf84]**, НО, когда я открываю тот же инспектор кода, у меня body не имеет дополнительный свойств. Просто тег  . Окей, если с этим проблему можно решить, в входной файл **app.vue** добавить  без **scoped**, то как быть с подключением шрифтов? Как вообще правильно подключить всё это дело?

Тут не столько проблема заключается в её решении, сколько в правильной постановки приложения. Меня не интересуют костыли, меня в большей степени интересует как правильно организовать подачу стилей и идти дальше, чтобы больше не встречать данных казусов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делаю так для каждого компонента отдельный файл стилей с именем `_myawesomesassfle.scss`.

Все что используется больше 2 раз выношу в файл `_variable.scss`, или `_mixins.scss`

В корне папки создаю главный файл `style.scss`/`main.scss` или как мне угодно. В него уже подключаю, базовые файлы:

```
@import "libs";

/* Utils */
@import "utils/variables";
@import "utils/mixins";
@import "utils/grid";
@import "utils/extends";
@import "utils/fonts";

/* Base */
@import "base/base";
```

а дальше просто уже файлы стилей компонентов, что бы не захламлять однофайловые компоненты.
В каждом компоненте есть рут элемент, которому даю класс, например `profile`, в `_profile.scss` пишу код с привязкой к класу, например:

```
.profile{
   // стили которые касаются только конкретного компонента
}
```

и при сборке проекта подключается уже один готовый минифицырованый файл

моя примерная структура:

```
├── base
│   └── _base.scss
├── includes
│   ├── _footer.scss
│   └── _header.scss
├── _libs.scss
├── style.scss
└── utils
    ├── _extends.scss
    ├── _fonts.scss
    ├── _grid.scss
    ├── _mixins.scss
    ├── _smart-grid.scss
    └── _variables.scss
```

Ну как-то так)

Структура `vue` компонента:

```
<template>
  <div class="myawesomeclass">
    <slot/>
  </div>
</template>

<static-query>
query {
  metadata {
    siteName
  }
}
</static-query>
<script>
  import Header from '../components/Header'
  import Footer from "../components/Footer";
  export default {
    components: {Header, Footer},
  }
</script>
<style lang="scss">
@import "../styles/myawesomefile";
</style>
```

Файл стилей этого компонента

```
.myawesomeclass{
  @include wrapper();
  &__list{

    @include flex_container(row, center, space-between);

    &__item{
      width: 262px;
      @include flex_container(column, center, center);

      .subtitle{
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        @include flex_container(row, center, space-between);
      }

      img{
        width: auto;
      }
    }

    @for $i from 1 through 4{
      &__item:nth-child(#{$i}){
        .subtitle{
          &::before{
            content: "#{$i}";
            font-size: 60px;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-style: normal;
            margin-right: 20px;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@include adaptive(tablet-sm){
  .myawesomeclass{
    &__list{

    }
  }
}

@include adaptive(mobile){
  .myawesomeclass{
    &__list{
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      &__item{
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
      }
    }
  }
}
@include adaptive(mobile){
  .myawesomeclass{
    &__list{
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
  }
}
```

и да адаптив я импортирую в каждый элемент отдельно, через `@include adaptive(mobile)` 
`adaptive` - это миксин, если что) почему я так делаю, да потому что мне так удобней, все четко разделено между собой)

Comment: Как  подключаются шрифты? Как изменяете body? Можно минимальный код базовой структуры, которая используется во всех файлах

Comment: шрифты в файлик `_fonts.scss` ) Код сейчас добавлю в  ответ

Comment: @MoloF дополнил ответ